# IIS Outbound Rules URL Rewrite Scheme for Anchor Tag Links

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting, iis-7

I've been trying to find some additional information on how one can perform a URL rewrite where the expected output is to remove / replace portions of the url.

For example, I want to ensure that all my anchor tags's href value will be modified.

```
<a class="button" href="https://www.oldgoogle.com" target="_blank">
<a class="button" href="https://www.oldgoogle.com/links" target="_blank">
<a class="button" href="https://www.oldgoogle.com/links/category?dosearch=true" target="_blank">
<a class="button" href="https://oldgoogle.com/nowww" target="_blank">
```

Such that the href value becomes like this:

```
<a class="button" href="https://newgoogle.com" target="_blank">
<a class="button" href="https://newoogle.com/links" target="_blank">
<a class="button" href="https://newgoogle.com/links/category?dosearch=true" target="_blank">
<a class="button" href="https://newgoogle.com/nowww" target="_blank">
```

Note that I am practically **removing the www** from the url as well as replacing **oldgoogle** with **newgoogle**.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
<rewrite>
  <outboundRules>
    <remove name="Strip WWW from Anchor Tags" />
    <rule name="Strip WWW from Anchor Tags" preCondition="IsHTML">
      <match filterByTags="A" pattern="^http(s)://www.oldgoogle.com/(.*)" />
      <conditions />
      <action type="Rewrite" value="https://newgoogle.com/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

Appreciate any information you can share to resolve this.

P.S. We can't modify the links coming from the source as these are all littered in a web of external text files, database tables, and other sources and some hard coded rules write the links as it is. So the only option I have on the table is to rewrite the links generated and emitted by the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the below rule:

```
<outboundRules>
              <rule name="rule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match filterByTags="A" pattern="http(s)://(www.)?oldgoogle.com(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="https://newgoogle.com{R:3}" />
            </rule>
            <preConditions>
                <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                    <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                </preCondition>
            </preConditions>
        </outboundRules>
```

[image]

[image]